# unity zfighting or objects climbing on top and bottom of each other?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d

I'm having an issue with 3d objects doing some kind of weird z fighting or climbing on top of each other depending on where the camera is moved to. I have posted some pictures to help illustrate the problem.  Each rectangular "building" contains textured cubes of all the same size. The corner cubes do overlap somewhat.  As you can see from the picture, every object is the same height. This is seen in the scene editor as well as the final rendered product. Can anyone explain what is causing this and how it can it possibly be fixed?  Thank you :)

[image: top view straight ahead]

[image: top view camera moved to right]

[image: side view]

Comment: You can try using the camera not in Perspective View, but in Orthographic.
for more reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html

Comment: It looks like disabled Z-buffer, could you verify if your materials use it (writing to Z-buffer to be precise) ?

Comment: wow ok so i figured out the possible issue when @kolenda mentioned materials and z buffer. I had the material on transparent and not opaque.. All though not sure why it would create that kind of effect??  Does anyone know.. I'l leave a few hours if someone wants to answer this with an explanation and knows why it had that specific effect?

Comment: also putting the camera in ortho mode did fix the issue as well.. but perspective just looks a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the texture using transparency shader. After googling there seemed to be all kinds of issues with the unity transparency shader that involve workarounds.  Two solutions to this is to either turn off transparency, or put the camera in orthographic mode.